# How can I dynamically create another text field by typing in the text field in Dart and Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[Please see the sample text field requested in the link](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/VIsNQiEl#link)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp1FU.jpg),I can make the text field dynamic by clicking on the icon and the button, but not by typing in the text field.

I asked a question on JPT chat and she answered this, and it works fine, but every time she adds a text field, I have to hit S control to create a new text field.

```
final List<TextEditingController> _controllers = [];
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _controllers.length + 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == _controllers.length) {
            // Return a new text field if we've reached the end of the list.
            final controller = TextEditingController();
            _controllers.add(controller);
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: TextField(
                controller: controller,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Enter text here',
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            // Return an existing text field.
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: TextField(
                controller: controllers[index],
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Enter text here',
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
```

```
my code
    ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: dynamicTextFeild.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      if (controller.selection == true) {
                        dynamicTextFeild.add(
                          DynamicTextFeild(
                            labelIndex: dynamicTextFeild.length,
                            controller: controller,
                          ),
                        );
                        return DynamicTextFeild(
                          labelIndex: dynamicTextFeild.length,
                          controller: controller,
                        );
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                  ),
```

After typing on the text field, a Dynamic Text Field should be created, which contains categories and text fields.

```
class DynamicTextFeild extends StatefulWidget {
  int labelIndex;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  DynamicTextFeild({
    Key? key,
    required this.labelIndex,
    required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DynamicTextFeild> createState() => _DynamicTextFeildState();
}

class _DynamicTextFeildState extends State<DynamicTextFeild> {
  String generiteLabel(int labelIndex) {
    if (labelIndex == 0) {
      return "phone...";
    } else if (labelIndex == 1) {
      return "phone...";
    } else if (labelIndex == 2) {
      return "phone...";
    } else if (labelIndex == 3) {
      return "phone...";
    } else if (labelIndex == 4) {
      return "phone...";
    } else if (labelIndex == 5) {
      return "phone...";
    } else if (labelIndex == 6) {
      return "phone...";
    } else if (labelIndex == 7) {
      return "phone...";
    } else if (labelIndex == 8) {
      return "phone...";
    } else if (labelIndex == 9) {
      return "phone...";
    } else if (labelIndex == 10) {
      return "phone...";
    } else {
      return generiteLabel.toString();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        const Expanded(flex: 1, child: Category()),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: TFF(
            controller: widget.controller,
            label: "phone...",
            left: 5.0,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I was able to create a text field by typing in the text field. But there is a problem that I have to enter a DynamicTextFeild and onChange manually every time, and this creates limitations. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I should do?

```
DynamicTextFeild(
            controller: controller,
            onChange: (p0) {
              String p0 = "";
              List<String> words = p0.split(" ");
              String firstWord = words[0];
              if (dynamicTextFeild.length == firstWord.length) {
                print(dynamicTextFeild.length);
                setState(
                  () {
                    dynamicTextFeild.add(
                      DynamicTextFeild(
                        lableIndex: labelIndex,
                        controller: TextEditingController(),
                        onChange: (Value) {
                          print(dynamicTextFeild.length);
                          if (Value.length == 1) {
                            setState(
                              () {
                                dynamicTextFeild.add(
                                  DynamicTextFeild(
                                    lableIndex: labelIndex,
                                    controller: TextEditingController(),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
                print(dynamicTextFeild.length);
              }
            },
            lableIndex: labelIndex,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: Get.width,
            height: 400,
            child: Column(
              children: dynamicTextFeild,
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: what is `DynamicTextFeild`?

Comment: https://filetransfer.io/data-package/VIsNQiEl#link

Comment: Watch this video

Comment: i think I've got what are you trying to do, but what is `DynamicTextFeild` you are using on your question. It can be simple TextEditingController

Comment: Dynamic text field is a customized widget that has a different label every time a new text field is created. In this way, I create a new text field by clicking the button, I want a new text field to be added when I start writing in the text field, according to the video.

Comment: How can I send you a more complete code? It has a character limit in the command

Comment: you can create a gist and attach on question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeasin Sheikh
 please check it